# How to autoSize table cells generated via iText

Tags: seam, itext

How to autoSize table cells which was generated by seam pdf [plugin](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest/en-US/html/itext.html#itext.tables) (via iText)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `widthPercentage`

```
<p:table columns="2" headerRows="1" widthPercentage="95">
```

Then your cells should automatically fill that width

Comment: I would prefer to autoSize within a column. The current mechanism seems to work, but sometimes wraps the text if it's too lengthy even though it has allocated more space to the other columns which have lesser data